# function to return the position of a value in an array (C++, Splashkit)

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have designed an array where the user enters in five names, and the terminal will print those names and identify the longest name. I'm now trying to introduce a function where the user enters a name, and if that name is in the array, to print the position of that name (if the name is not there, print -1). I'm using the Splashkit library which is a little different. I've tried a few different variations but no luck so far. This is what I have...

```
int index_of(string value, string names[], int size)
{
    value = read_string("Enter name to find index: ");
    
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       if ((names[i]) == string(value))
       {
           return i;
           write_line("The index is: ");
           write(i);
       }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

It compiles fine but just won't work, even when I call it in main. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks :)

```
int main()
{
    #define SIZE 5
    string names[SIZE];
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while( i < SIZE )
    {
        names[i] = read_string("Enter a name:");
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        write_line(names[i]);
    }

    int total;
    total = total_length(names, SIZE);

    write("Total length: ");
    write_line(total);

    bool has_connor;
    has_connor = contains(names, SIZE, "connor");

    if ( has_connor ) write_line("contains Connor");
    
    write("The longest name is: ");
    write_line(longest_name(names, SIZE));

    int index_of(int value, string names[], int size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are returning from the function before `write_line()` and `write()`. I think that is wrong. Also can you provide the code snippet from where `index_of()` is called?

Comment: Hi Kuro, so it's down the end of my main, I just have "  int index_of(int value, string names[], int size);  "

Comment: then can you paste the `main()` as well?

Comment: Have updated in description :)

Comment: In your code you are not calling the function `index_of()`. You may want to change the  line before return of `main()` to `int index = index_of({}, names, SIZE)`. Also I don't think you need the `value` in `index_of()` as parameter.

Comment: You can just declare `value` as local variable of `index_of()` instead of a function parameter

Comment: Inside of `main` you are declaring another version of `index_of` that takes an `int` rather than a `string` as its first parameter. I don't see where either of these are being called.

Answer (score 0):

I think that these lines `write_line("The index is: "); write(i);` are useless because return comes before them. try

```
write_line("The index is: ");
write(i);
return i;
```

Comment: Hey I tried that and it didn't make a difference :/

Comment: then Please send me the exact output and error you are facing.